# Angularjs and Laravel Configuration

Tags: angularjs, laravel

Hi I am using **`Angularjs`** & **`Laravel`**

**`home.blade.php`**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Dashboard</div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                    You are logged in! {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                    <div  class="text-center" ng-controller="HelloController">Hi [[ name ]] welcome to AngularJS Tutorial Series</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

**`public\controllers\homeController`**

**`homeController.js`**

```
MyApp.controller('HelloController', hello);

function hello($scope)
{
    $scope.name = "Test";
}
```

**`app.blade.php`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/homeController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/aboutController.js"></script>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script>
        window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]); ?>
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-app="MyApp">
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                        {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        &nbsp;
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @if (Auth::guest())
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/register') }}">Register</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ url('/logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            Logout
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ url('/logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's working fine but my doubt is This is the proper way or not. Please suggest me How to use **`Angularjs`** in **`laravel`**

I already work on Angularjs Project But I don't know how to configure Initial Configuration

Comment: what do you mean by "proper way"? because, my answer will depend on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: In Controller they written different way like they include module name etc...

Comment: I also want to know basic folder structure and all

Comment: I see, by what you say including other module, you're probably referring to `Single Responsibility` of the controllers? The question is kind of vague, but I can suggest some best practice articles that might help you start with what you're trying to accomplish. Read this style guide from John Papa ([Angular 1](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md), [Angular 2](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a2/README.md)).